# Custom Tabs Themeforest Fabia theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, custom, seo

I'm using the theme, Fabia, from themeforest, and I cannot for the life of me get rid of the "Custom Tab 1" and "Custom Tab 2" tabs by the product description. They default to a description of Lorem Ipsum and I've seen it on other sites. I'm trying to minimize duplicate content and I just want to get rid of them, as I don't need custom tabs, but I can't even find the option anywhere. Is anyone else using this theme that has run into this problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

This type of question is likely off topic because there are just too many themes and theme vendors to support all of them well - but as your'e a first-timer I'm happy to oblige.

I've never had any experience with Ultimo, but a quick Google search turned up the following:

> These blocks are only for static content (they are global, not
>   product-specific). How to create those tabs – it is described in the
>   user guide. Static blocks in Magento are global, can’t be assigned to
>   a specific page or product.
>
> There are two other tabs on product page for product-specific info: 1
>   – Description: which displays product long description 2 – Additional
>   Info: which displays product attributes. You can enable/disable each
>   attribute’s visibility on product page with “Visible on Product View
>   Page on Front-end” field in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes >
>   [attribute] >Frontend Properties.

According to this it sounds as though it will **always be static** and therefore will not avoid the duplicate content issues you're concerned about.

I suggest that you follow the instructions above to disable the applicable attributes.

HTH! Cheers.

---

<sub>Source:</sub>

http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798/comments?page=104&filter=all#comment_3974830

Answer (score 0):

Look for the file
app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/layout -> catalog.xml
Find this

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">

    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">

        <alias>description</alias>

        <title>Description</title>

        <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>

        <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>

    </action>
```

Comment out or remove both custom tabs :)

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">custom tab 1 code</action>




 <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">custom tab 2 code</action>
```